# Prove that f is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $f=u+iv$ an analytic function in a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$.If $u=h\circ v$ for some differentiable function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that f is constant.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If you show any effort to solve, people solve this instantly. (You should say any theorem related to this)

Comment: Sorry, well I try this: Apply Cauchy Riemman in du/dx=dv/dy and du/dy=-dv/dx. Then apply partial derivative to u=h(v(x,y)): du/dx=du/dh(dh/dx) + du/dv(dv/dx) and du/dy=du/dh(dh/dy) + du/dv(dv/dy) correct?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The Cauchy-Riemann equations yield $$(h' \circ v) \cdot v_x=v_y \\ (h' \circ v) \cdot v_y=-v_x.$$

Comment: I Apply Cauchy Riemman in du/dx=dv/dy and du/dy=-dv/dx. Then apply partial derivative to u=h(v(x,y)): du/dx=du/dh(dh/dx) + du/dv(dv/dx) and du/dy=du/dh(dh/dy) + du/dv(dv/dy) correct?

Comment: @carpediemfg you need to be more precise. $h$ is a function of one real variable only, thus using dh/dx and dh/dy is confusing (and not entirely valid as well). use $h'$ instead.